# Windows mounted network drives slow after upgrading switch

Tags: windows, networking, switch, mappeddrive

On our small business network our old 10/100 consumer grade switch gave up the ghost, and we replaced it with a proper business-grade gigabyte switch. After wiring it in our Linux and Mac users immediately got back to working off of network drives;

But 2 of our 3 Windows 7 PCs have suddenly experienced a tremendous slowdown with mapped network drives; Windows will become stuck "discovering" a folder causing applications to freeze when trying to open files. It will instantly display and browse files, but the moment you try to open one the bug hits. To remedy this we have our users copying files to the desktop, but it can take a few minutes while windows is stuck "calculating" the time it will take to copy. These aren't big files, mostly excel sheets less than 500KB - these operations are instant on Linux and Mac.

(The third Windows machine is having no issues)

I've tried remapping the drives, mapping to different drive letters, rebooting, etc. I'm at a loss, because switches are mostly transparent, and it's only after the switch was replaced that the Windows PCs started acting up. What black-magic voodoo am I missing to make Windows work?

Thank you.

Comment: are *all* network drives having problems, on only ones on a certain fileserver? Are these machines set to autonegotiate, or have their speed manually set?

Comment: We only have one fileserver, but multiple drives are mapped to it on each computer. One windows machine is fine, all other windows machines are having issues. Non-windows machines are fine also. Everything is set to use the defaults, so it should be autonegotiate.

Comment: so the linux and mac clients have no problem connecting to the *same* shares? Have all the Windows clients been fully patched and rebooted?

Comment: I performed an update on one of the machines during my initial troubleshooting process - no effect. I also restored it to the earliest working restore point which I knew had functioned correctly (before the update), also to no effect. EDIT: Mac/Linux are accessing the same shares.

Comment: I would [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) the machine while it's freezing to determine if it's network based or not.

Comment: I'll report back when I have some info from Wireshark, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14799/discussion-between-bighomie-and-kver).

Comment: How old are those computers? It might be that they are being overwhelmed with more packets than they have CPU power to handle.

Comment: Are all windows machines and fileserver negotiating at the same speed with the switch? Are the problem windows machines negotiating at a different speed than what the file server negotiates at? Do the 2 machines that don't work share the same make/model of NIC compared to the one that has no issues? What make of switch is your "business grade gigabit" switch?

Comment: Found the problem; We had a momentary powerout (I bumped the off switch on our surge protector) during the switch change, and our fileserver had not properly closed/cleaned/disconnected from the affected machines; I did a proper reboot on the file server and the issue has resolved. If it continues to work properly, I'll formally answer my question. So, yeah, I didn't follow rule #1 in IT: "Have you tried restarting it?" - only I should have also restarted the server in this case.